# How to calculate the standard deviation of the C-index?

Tags: r, cox-model, concordance

I fitted a `coxph` model and below is the concordance details from my object named `cx`.

I can see that `Concordance` is calculated as `4282/(4283+1697) = 0.716` but I'd like to know:

(1) How is `se=0.048` calculated?

(2) What does `std(c-d)` represent and how is it calculated?

```
> summary(cx)
Concordance= 0.716  (se = 0.048 )
Rsquare= 0.098   (max possible= 0.852 )
Likelihood ratio test= 20.41  on 2 df,   p=3.707e-05
Wald test            = 21.07  on 2 df,   p=2.665e-05
Score (logrank) test = 21.07  on 2 df,   p=2.654e-05


> cx$concordance
concordant discordant  tied.risk  tied.time   std(c-d) 
4283.0000  1697.0000     0.0000     3.0000   576.6328
```